# Why doesn't Din Djarin have a clan or clan colours?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian, mandalorian

While it is established that Din Djarin is a foundling, every other Mandalorian we've seen so far seems to have their own clan colours. He also doesn't have a clan other than being a 'clan of 2' with young Grogu, earning his own sigil a fair amount of time after becoming a bounty hunter. His 'initial' armour was brown (and he already had his 'upgraded' helmet) and ill-fitting.

[image]

He eventually ends up in super-shiny armour - which no other Mandalorian seems to have.

Clan Kryze has their own colours:

[image]

As does House Vizla:

[image]

Even Boba Fett seems to be quite proud of his armour, repainting it to look nearly new once he recovers it. That said, his father's armour was different.

(Spoilers for season 3 follow.)

> In the first episode of season 3 we see a young Mandalorian taking the oath. While there's a mix of paint schemes, the young Mandalorian's helmet is painted in the same scheme as Paz Visla - and Paz seems protective of him. His helmet and that of the other young Mandalorians are painted. No-one else has plain shiny chrome armour.
>
>  [image]

Why *is* Din's armour shiny and chrome while nearly every other Mandalorian has a personal or clan paint scheme?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with him being a foundling?

Comment: I considered that but every other mandalorian we have seen isn't chromed out, and I would assume he can't be the only foundling

Comment: Maybe it's not The Way?

Comment: Mando's colour scheme is any colour you like, so long as it's chrome.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that there is a canonical answer to this yet. But I think we know enough to come up with a plausible reason. And in my opinion this is two-part.

**1. The Tribe**
Din belongs to a "clan" called [the Tribe](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Tribe). But the Tribe is not a clan in the traditional sense. While it functions as a clan, it's an assortment of Mandalorians who are members of the [Children of the Watch](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Watch). The Children are considered a religious group - hence their adherence to "the Way" - and are most likely the heirs of the [Death Watch](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Death_Watch?so=search).

It doesn't seem like the Tribe has its own color scheme. In fact, [Paz Vizsla](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Paz_Vizsla) is a member of the Tribe and uses his house's traditional color scheme. In season 3, episode 1, we see the Tribe during a ceremony. The Mandalorians present sport a number of different color schemes. So it stands to reason that the Tribe - and possibly the Children of the Watch in general - retain their traditional clan colors. Din was accepted as a foundling into the Children and later the Tribe. But he was not accepted into one of the traditional family clans and thus, has no color scheme he could use for his armor.

Keep in mind that foundlings do not always join the Mandalorians. By creed they must be cared for until reunited with their kin or until they come of age. What they do afterwards is their decision. Foundlings can create their own clans but we don't know if adoption into an existing clan is common or even done at all.

**2. Clan Mudhorn**
As stated above, foundlings may create their own clan. The Armorer called Din and Grogu a "clan of two", implying that Din has created his own clan. Canonically they are called [Clan Mudhorn](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Clan_Mudhorn), after Din's signet. That seems to imply, that Din could come up with his own color scheme but hasn't done so yet.